# How to convert python list of interger to list of hex, getting List error "struct.error: required argument is not an integer"

Tags: python, list

I have a list that is the `a=[0,1]` and I want to change with  `a=[0x00,0x001]` type. How can I do this? I tried this way

```
print (struct.pack('>h',a))
```

But I cannot change to hex

Comment: You mean to convert integers to strings that look like their hex representation, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

Using hex directly should work:

```
>>> a = [0,1]
>>> a = [hex(i) for i in a]
>>> a
['0x0', '0x1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [hex(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) will only give you the least amount of leading 0:

```
print( [hex(i) for i in [0,1]])  #  ['0x1', '0x2']
```

You can [format(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) the string as hex and [zfill()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) the needed amount of zeros and prepending `'0x'` to it yourself:

```
data = [0,1]

as_hex = [ "0x" + format(e,"x").zfill(2) for e in data]

print(as_hex)
```

Output:

```
['0x00', '0x01']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to ask last question about this if i have  [0x00,0x05] data how can i translate to '0005' form

Comment: @DuyguDemirpence  `''.join(  (k[2:] for k in ['0x00','0x05']) )` to glue both together.

Answer (score 1):

As you fail to describe what your wanted outcome is, I can only guess:

1. Do you want to pack some numbers to a string?

   Then it doesn't matter which format you use, both should work as soon as you use the correct format string:

   ```
   a = [1, 2]
   b = [0x01, 0x02]
   struct.pack(">hh", *a)
   # > '\x00\x01\x00\x02'
   struct.pack(">hh", *b)
   # > '\x00\x01\x00\x02'
   ```

   This is because `a` and `b` are equal: it doesn't matter if you write `1` and `2` or if you prefer `0x01` resp. `0x02`. Be aware that the displayed strings are just representations of strings containing special characters with the values 0, 1 and 2, respectively.
2. Do you want to output your numbers in a hexadecimal representation?

   In this case, see the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the another way of converting you list of integer to list of hex

```
a = [0,1]
b = map(hex, a) 
# or 
b = map(lambda x:hex(x), a)
# output
print b
['0x1', '0x2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the another way of converting a list of integer to list of hex using a map function:

```
a=[0,1]
print(map(hex,a))
# Output
# ['0x0', '0x1']
```